# Can the matrix representation of a product of disjoint cycles be made up of the matrix representation of each cycle?

Tags: matrices, permutations, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

Let $\rho \in S_n$ be a permutation and its matrix representation be $M(\rho)$ where $M: S_n \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C}^n)$.

Then writing out $M(\rho)$ is very easy. But now if we represent $\rho$ as the product of disjoint cycles, ie $\rho = (\rho_1 \rho_2 \cdots \rho_n)$ where each $\rho_i$ is a cycle, then is there a way of writing the matrix representation of this product by using the matrix representation of each cycle. i.e. can we write $M(\rho)$ by using each $M(\rho_i)$.

For example if we have $(1 2 3)(4 5)$, its matrix representation is $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $ which is in block diagonal form (I don't know how to latex that) and so clearly makes use of the matrix for both $(1 2 3)$ and $(4 5)$.

But if we have $(2 3 4)(1 5) \in S_5$, its matrix representation is $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $ which is not made up of the matrix for $(2 3 4)$ and the one for $(1 5)$.

The reason for this question is I am trying to find a formula for the determinant of a permutation minus the identity (i.e. $\det(M(\rho) - I)$). I believe that this is the product of each $\det(M(\rho_1) - I)$ but this would only make sense if $M(\rho)$ could be written as the block diagonal with each $M(\rho_i)$ being a block.

As a side note, why is the matrix representation of $(1 2 3)(4 5)$ not the matrix representation of $(1 2 3)$ times the matrix representation of $(4 5)$. The product of these two $5 \times 5$ matrices gives me $0$ instead of the result above. Intuitively should the matrix representation of the composition of two cycles not be the product of their matrix representations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to compute $\det(M(\rho) - I)$,

then for $\rho=(a_1\,a_2\,\ldots\,a_k)(b_1\,b_2\ldots\,b_j)\ldots$

you might want to define a new basis $w_1,w_2,\ldots$ such that

$w_1=e_{a_1}$, $w_2=e_{a_2}$, ... , $w_k=e_{a_k}$,

$w_{k+1}=e_{b_1}$, $w_{k+2}=e_{b_2}$, ... , $w_{k+j}=e_{b_j}$, etc.

Denoting by $S$ the matrix that changes the vector basis from $\{e_i\}$ to $\{w_i\}$, we have that $SM(\rho)S^{-1}$ is in block form.

Now, $\det(M(\rho)-I)=\det(SM(\rho)S^{-1}-I)$.

$\\$

As for your side note,

> As a side note, why is the matrix representation of (123)(45) not the matrix representation of (123) times the matrix representation of (45). The product of these two 5×5 matrices gives me 0 instead of the result above.

Have you made sure that the matrix representation of $(123)$ has diagonal entries $a_{4,4}=a_{5,5}=1$ instead of $0$? You can regard $(123)$ as $(123)(4)(5)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I understand correctly, you are saying that $M(\rho)$ is similar to a block diagonal matrix, and we get this result by making a change of basis. Could you please clarify what this new basis is: e.g is $e_{a_1}$ the vector with $0$'s everywhere except for in the $a_1$ position where there is a 1? Also how does this tell us that $M(\rho)$ is similar to a block diagonal matrix. Sorry if these questions seem silly I'm just struggling to visualise this. As for the side note you are correct - I forgot to put 1's in the diagonal.

Comment: You can also think about a linear transformation $T$ that sends $u\to u'\to u''\to u$, and $v\to w\to v$, where $u,u',u'',v,w$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Then the span of $u,u',u''$ is an invariant subspace of $T$. So is the span of $v,w$. @Jamal

Comment: An important perspective in linear algebra is to think about a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ as one function, and to think about your matrix for $T$ as depending on your choice of basis for $V$. In this case that may be more useful than regarding the matrix itself as the function. Then it's worth knowing what are the properties of $T$, irrespective of the particular basis chosen for $V$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now understand what you mean with the change of basis. I tested this change of basis with a few small examples and did indeed get that $M(\rho)$ is similar to a block diagonal. Could you please explain or point me in the direction of a resource as to why we end up with such a nice block diagonal. I get that we know the general have of $S$ and $M(\rho)$ so is it simply a case of multiplying out $S M(\rho) S^{-1}$? Thanks

Comment: @Jamal My advice would be to improve your understanding of how different matrices (in this case $M(\rho)$ on the one hand and the block diagonal on the other hand) represent the same linear transformation. Here's a link I got from a Google search. https://conf.math.illinois.edu/~rotman/similarity.pdf  good luck

Comment: The matrix for (12)(345) and the matrix for (13)(245) are similar, because both represent a linear transformation which sends $t$ to $u$ and $u$ to $t$, and which sends $v$ to $w$ and $w$ to $x$ and $x$ to $v$, where $t,u,v,w,x$ are linearly independent vectors in a five-dimensional vector space. Again, my advice would be that you try to understand this point, using either that link I gave or some other link you might find about this topic, and if you don't succeed, there's still a good chance you'll understand it as you read more on linear algebra. I think I'll end it here, good luck!